# "Authoring" versus "Writing"

Tags: differences

In my area of work the word *author* as a verb has become quite common. However, it seems to have a subtly different meaning than plain vanilla *write*. For example, one does not write software unit tests; one authors them.

Can anyone offer a clear distinction between the two words? Has *author* as a verb become a common usage outside of the field of computer software?

Comment: Writing unit tests sounds **much** better to me than authoring unit tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would understood this subtle difference connotational-wise where authoring includes a higher level of creativity or other mental use. I would also say that all authoring is writing, but that not all writing is authoring.

Comment: I have no idea why you got marked down. I think your answer is probably exactly right. So I will accept it.

Comment: Neither do I, but thank you for the acceptance.

Answer (score 5):

The verb *[author](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/author_2)* either means to write something (a book) or to create something (a computer program). I see no reason why one cannot use *[write](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/write)* for both purposes.

Answer (score 2):

[Oxford Dictionaries Pro](http://english.oxforddictionaries.com/%20d) defines the verb *author* as ‘be the author of (a book or piece of writing)’ and ‘be the originator of’. The [OED](http://www.oed.com/) has similar definitions, with the earliest citation dated 1598. However, when *author* means ‘to be the author or originator of (a book, play, remark, etc.)’ it is described as ‘obsolete except in U.S. use’. As a BrEng speaker I would not use it as a verb at all, but if it is being used for a specific purpose in the computing industry, then so be it.

Answer (score 0):

Many English teachers and texts will always opt for write as the verb instead of author. It sounds pretentious as well as being a less preferred form.

Comment: Could you italicise the quoted verbs, please?

Answer (score -1):

I believe that the meaning of writing is a subset of the meaning of authoring, similarly to the way that writer is a subset of author (noun). I use author when I don't wish to emphasis the manner in which a work was created. I would apply it to art, music, writing (including writing programs), or perhaps in more metaphorical senses: authoring a city, i.e. building it, founding it, etc.